# Delayed Job not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added following code . but can't able to send bulk mail.

Gemfile

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Controller

```
def send_news_letter  

    @emails = Array.new
      if params[:newsletter].present?
        @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:newsletter].keys).first
      end

      if params[:students].present?
        @emails = @emails + Student.all
        #raise @emails.inspect

      end

      if params[:teachers].present?
        @emails = @emails +Teacher.all
      end


    if params[:parents].present?
        @emails = @emails + Parent.all
      end

      UserMailer.delay.send_multiple_email(@emails,@newsletter)

      redirect_to newsletters_url, :notice => "Delivering Newsletter"
  end
```

mailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def send_multiple_email(emails,newsletter)
      @emails = emails
      #raise @emails.inspect
      @newsletter = newsletter
      mail(:to => @emails.map(&:email), subject: "Deliver")
  end

end
```

Actually it redirecting the index page of the newsletter. But it won't send mail..

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do to check out what is happening:

1. Is this in development? As a beginner I could not figure out how to run both `bundle exec rake jobs work` and `rails s` at the same time in development. I had to stop the server and execute the rake task, then start the server again.
2. Interrogate the database (such as using `rails c`) to determine if the job has been saved to the database. That way you know it is ready to be executed.
3. Cannot find any database records? Delayed job creates its own table so obviously you need to have your database migrated. Use the commands as per Github:

   `rails generate delayed_job:active_record`

   `rake db:migrate`
4. Check out the Railscasts episode on how to use it.